# GCP: Unable to pull docker images from our GCP private container registry on ubuntu/debian VM instances

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, virtual-machine, google-container-registry

I am trying to pull a docker container from our private GCP container registry on a regular VM instance (i.e. `ubuntu-1904`) running on Google Cloud, but I am getting the following error:

```
user@test ~ $ sudo docker pull example.io/docker-dev/name:v01

Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

I followed those instructions, i.e., run the `gcloud auth configure-docker` command, which outputs a success message.

However, when running the `docker pull` command again, I get the exact same error.

A couple of extra tests that might help to provide feedback:

- If I pull from a different registry, it works (for example, `docker run hello-world` pulls and runs the `hello-world` image)
- I tested the same command (`docker pull example.io/docker-dev/name:v01`) on my local computer (Mac) instead of the vm instance and works perfectly.
- I have also created vm instances and enable the option "Deploy a container image to this VM instance", providing the container address (`example.io/docker-dev/name:v01`), and also works. However, I don't want to use this option because it selects automatically a "Container-Optimized" boot disk, which I prefer not to use [due to the limitations](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits#limitations)

**Question**:
Why I cannot pull docker images from my private container registry on a Ubuntu o Debian VM, even though docker seems to work very well pulling images from other repositories (docker hub)?

Answer (score 9):

I did this yesterday. Just run `gcloud auth configure-docker` then run

```
VERSION=2.0.0
OS=linux  # or "darwin" for OSX, "windows" for Windows.
ARCH=amd64  # or "386" for 32-bit OSs, "arm64" for ARM 64.
```

After that you can download the docker-credential-gcr

```
wget "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr/releases/download/v${VERSION}/docker-credential-gcr_${OS}_${ARCH}-${VERSION}.tar.gz"
```

Then run

```
tar cvzf --to-stdout ./docker-credential-gcr_linux_amd64-2.0.0.tar.gz /usr/bin/docker-credential-gcloud && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-credential-gcloud
```

And finally run

```
gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://gcr.io
```

Now you will be able to pull you image :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and is required when you aren't running container-os which already has it installed. NOTE: `tar` yells at you about how you're using the slash for the path for some reason. `tar: Removing leading '/' from member names
tar: /usr/bin/docker-credential-gcloud: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Answer (score 7):

For me, on a container-os optimized instance, it helped to just run:

```
docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
```

https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-container-instance#starting_a_docker_container_via_cloud-config

Note the [default policy](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) for compute instances:

> VM instances, including those in Google Kubernetes Engine clusters,
>   must have the correct storage access scopes configured to push or pull
>   images. By default, VMs can pull images when Container Registry is in
>   the same project.

Comment: Interesting, we selected the container option while creating the instance; though they would have run this automatically. 

Answer (score 0):

If you run gcloud auth configure-docker, the auth information is saved under your personal directory. 
When you then run sudo docker pull example.io/docker-dev/name:v01, it looks for auth info under root directory and doesn't find anything there.

You should run both with or without sudo.